# Foley: Dog Feet

Tags: foley, footsteps, animals

Hey guys.

I'm trying to record/design some dog footsteps. any suggestions? I dont have a dog and havent seen a dogs feet for a while but from what I remember their quite hardened, kind of plasticy sounding..??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leather work gloves with Lee Press On Nails glued to them.

Good luck.

Comment: @Justin.haha. didnt quite know what you meant unitl I googled and found this rad advert from the 80's. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3amCM8_JeMY nice one. ive got some leather gloves so now just need to find some stick on nails(which wont be hard). I can imagine the sound already. THANKS!!

Comment: @Justin. leather gloves with fake nails worked a treat dude. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I that not to long ago. i used leather gloves with plastic spoons taped to my fingernails. Works fine. On another note  dogs are a bit difficult for perfect sync. 4 feet.  I found that the easiest approach is to sync the feet you see when the dog starts walking and stops walking, everything in between is more about rhythm than sync.

Comment: @Vidar. ha, yeah i was wandering about sync issues when watching the animatic. Especially because this dog looses a leg part way through and is down to a 3legged hoppy walk. Thanks for the rhythm tip!!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a quick way to do it, I think you can get an effective sound by taping a small piece of paper to the end of your fingers and also taping paper clips onto your nails for the claws!

And mic nice and close!

Answer (score 1):

My favorite for this is very soft lamb-skin gloves (so there will be no creaks) with paper clips on all fingers :-)
It's no problem simulating a quadrupedal animal as they do not set down more than one foot at a time while walking. Even for running in full speed, no animal puts down more than two feet at the same time, that includes jumping. When jumping, a take off starts with the fore legs taking off first, followed by both the hind-legs pushing off, lifting at the same time, with a slight scratch in the ground. When landing, as far as I remember right now, both forefeet enter at the same time, taking most of the impact thus being a little harder, followed by the hind-feet, but here it seems a little different from individual to individual how they land. My old Golden Retriever used to land first with both forefeet no matter what kind of jump, but when hopping down from the sofa she used to still have one paw left in it while taking support with the first hind-paw, then when stabilized, she put down the other as well. Seems like smaller dogs generally tends to move more symmetrically than bigger, though it might just be the dogs I know behaving that way. Though I seriously doubt that :-)

Remember, it's less of what you use as props and more how good you are to mimic dog-walk that nails if it looks convincible or not :-)

Comment: @Christian. yes from what I continue to learn on foley it is all about the performance. and thats cool with me, its like acting but not just as a human. getting a 'ball park' idea about the sound was what i was stumped on. The two legs on the ground at a time is a GREAT point, thanks. It did cross my mind acutally but forgot to look it up. Cheers Christian.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for asking a question within your question, but how can you replicate something like this?

[soundcloud]stephensaldanha/the-bichon-buzzer[/soundcloud]

Comment: Pomeranian + crack ?

Comment: Actually it's a bit bigger than that isn't it... The crack still stands though.

Comment: Dog-mimicing gloves, some paper bag props, a good floor, your voice, and a pitchshifter.
And of course a knack for performing stuff like this :-)

Answer (score 0):

I heard a dog nailing along a concrete path yesterday.  Plastic on concrete, +1 to the gloves approach.

Answer (score 0):

chicken feet or pigs trotters

Comment: @WAudio.hmmmm interesting. I guess you can buy these from the butcher?

Comment: yep order them in and keep some spares in the freezer. They obviously don't last that long.